# Getting the number of words on a webpage issue php

Tags: php

I am trying to get the number of words that a domain web page has, but I get way larger numbers than expected. For example on Google.com with my function I get 180 words, and counted manually there are about 30. I noticed that it also includes the words from style tags and javascript tags, that is a bit odd. I also checked this http://www.seoreviewtools.com/bulk-web-page-word-count-checker/ and it's counting only 6.
Where am I mistaking?

```
function get_page_stats($domain) {
    $str = file_get_contents($domain);
    $str = strip_tags(strtolower($str));
    $words = str_word_count($str, 1);
    $words = array_count_values($words); // added as per Avinash Babu answer
    var_dump($words);
}
get_page_stats('http://google.com');
```

Comment: strip_tags doesn't remove the parts between <script> </script> tags, it just removes the tags themselves. You'll have to check everything between the <body></body> tags at the very least, but even that can contain <script>, so you might want to filter that out as well.

Comment: Also, much content is generated on the fly via javascript. It's difficult to get an exact number for a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to filter very well by removing the style tags and the script tags from the entire web page.

```
function get_page_stats($domain) {
    $str = file_get_contents($domain);
    $str = preg_replace('/<style\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/style>/s', '', $str);
      // remove everything between the style tags
    $str = preg_replace('/<script\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/script>/s', '', $str);
      // remove everything between the script tags
    $str = strip_tags(strtolower($str));
      // remove html tags
    $words = str_word_count($str, 1);
    $words = array_count_values($words);
      // count the words
    var_dump($words);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_count_values()` for this.

A simple example

```
<?php
$str = '<h1>Hello</h1> this will show <a href="ur_html_file">word</a> count of all word used this time... hello!';

print_r(array_count_values(str_word_count(strip_tags(strtolower($str)), 1)));
```

Comment: hmm, it seams that it filtered a bit better but not enough. getting 70 for google.com and it includes values like function, window, yaw, for, var... I don't see them in the page, only in the html code.

Comment: if you're stripping tags and there's scripts in the markup, you'll be counting javascript in there, right?

Comment: @Hammerstein That is true, I am trying to figure out how to do it with regex

Comment: i am not good regex .but as you said regex can be helpful in matching the strings in the webpage and fetch the result

Comment: Manage to do it, added  `$str = preg_replace('/<style\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/style>/s', '', $str);
 $str = preg_replace('/<script\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/script>/s', '', $str);` after file get contents and it filtered very well.

Comment: glad to know you found ur solution..:)

Comment: anyway, thanks for the array_count_values, you have 1 up vote from me.